# how to I test that my event hanlder was called when FileReader triggers load event

Tags: typescript, jasmine

In one of my methods, I am using `FileReader` to read a file. I suppose that `FileReader` will trigger `load` event once file gets loaded asynchronously.

```
handleFileSelect(files:ArrayLike<File>){
...
      reader.onload = this.handleReaderLoaded;


      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
```

I want to test that `handleReaderLoaded` was called but I am unable to write the spec for it in `Jasmine`.

The spec I have written is thus far is

```
fit('should create a thumbnail of the image file selected', () => {
    let newPracticeQuestionComponent = component;

    let file1 = new File(["foo1"], "foo1.txt");//create file
    spyOn(newPracticeQuestionComponent,'handleReaderLoaded')//this is the load event handler 
    newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect([file1]);//handleFileSelect will create FileReader and will also start file load operation 
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleReaderLoaded).toHaveBeenCalled();




  });
```

The spec fails with reason `Expected spy handleReaderLoaded to have been called.`. I suppose the error happens because file loading is async and the spec finishes before the load event is triggered. How do I make the spec wait for the `load` event to be fired.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way seem to be using `done` method of `JAsmine` which probably instructs `Jasmine` to wait

```
  fit('should create a thumbnail of the image file selected', (done) => {
    let newPracticeQuestionComponent = component;
    expect(newPracticeQuestionComponent.consecutiveIdGenerator).toBe(0);
    let file1 = new File(["foo1"], "foo1.txt");
    spyOn(newPracticeQuestionComponent,'handleReaderLoaded').and.callFake(function(event){
      console.log("called fake implementation of handleReaderLoaded ",event);
      expect(event.type).toEqual("load");
      done();
    });
    newPracticeQuestionComponent.handleFileSelect([file1]);    

  });
```